# Is "wait up!" considered correct English?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

I thought if you wanted someone to wait for you, you would say, "wait for me". However, I've heard/seen a lot of people speak/write "wait up" instead. Is "wait up" correct English?

Comment: Correct or not, it is redundant; just say "Wait!"

Comment: @Emre. It's not redundant, It has the effect of softening the request.

Comment: This question is easily answered using a [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wait+up)...

Comment: I think this is a pretty common colloquialism in American English. The equivalent British English term would be *"hold on"* or *"hold on a minute"*

Comment: @MikeJ-UK: ...which also works in AmE, "hold on" that is.

Comment: "Hang on" also works in British English. (cf. @MikeJ-UK)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Collins Cobuild Advanced Learner's English Dictionary:

> *wait up*
>
> 1. If you wait up, you deliberately do not go to bed, especially because you are expecting someone to return home late at night.
> 2. If you ask someone to wait up, you are asking them to go more slowly or to stop and wait for you [AM, INFORMAL]

Comment: I thought it was incorrect but am pleasantly surprised to find that it does have a meaning! Thanks to all comments and answers.

Answer (score 3):

Actually "Wait up" comes when

> 1.To postpone going to bed in anticipation of something or someone.
>   2. Informal To stop or pause so that another can catch up: *Let's wait
>   up for the stragglers*.

Comment: In the Keifer Sutherland remake of "The Three Musketeers," critics were highly displeased by an anachronistic scene in which D'Artagnan shouts, "Hey guys, wait up!"

Answer (score -1):

Wait up, seems to be used in movies and novels but I have never heard it used in day to day talking. I believe it is outdated and pretentious.

Comment: It is neither outdated nor pretentious. It is perfectly commonplace in normal, everyday speech.